# MultiValueConverter - NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, multibinding

Have a little annoying problem with my requirements and hope its possible to solve.

Lets assume you have the following classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FooB> FooBs { get; set; }
}

public class FooB
{
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Now the `Foo` class has a list of `FooB` with given`Id1` and `Id2` values and a `Sum` Value that gets calculated.

In my WPF User Interface, I have `2 ComboBoxes` and `1 DataGrid`.
1 ComboBox hold information about the `Id1` and the other about `Id2`.

Now in my DataGrid, I have a list of `Foo` displayed with 2 Columns one is obviously the Name, but the other gives me a headache right now.

The second column should display the `Sum` property of the `"correct" FooB` class.

The correct FooB class is determined by the 2 ComboBoxes in the UI and there SelectedItem.

What I have done so far is create 2 Properties in my CodeBehind: (Notice they actually have backingfields and PropertyChanged specified I reduced the code to my main problem)

```
public int SelectedId1 { get; set; }
public int SelectedId2 { get; set; }
```

Those two properties are bound to the corresponding ComboBox:

```
<c1:C1ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Id1s}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedId1}" />
<c1:C1ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Id2s}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedId2}" />
```

My DataGrid so far looks like this:

```
<local:BindingProxy x:Key="BindingProxy"
                    Data="{Binding}" />

<DataGrid ItemsSource={Bindings Foos}>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetCorrectFooB}">
                    <Binding Binding="."></Binding>
                    <Binding Binding="Data.SelectedId1"></Binding>
                    <Binding Binding="Data.SelectedId2"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

(Notice the BindingProxy is from here: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ - to enable getting Data from the Window within the DataContext of a DataGridRow)

The Converter looks like this:

```
public class GetCorrectFooB : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var foo = (Foo)values[0];
        var id1 = (int) values[1];
        var id2 = (int) values[2];

        return foo.FooBs.First(x => x.Id1 == id1 && x.Id2 == id2).Sum;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works pretty well for now, even behaves correctly when I change values in the 2 ComboBoxes in UI and updates information correspondingly BUT... when the underlying Sum PropertyChanges and is getting notified by PropertyChanges the UI does not update.

Its working fine if I would just bind the column to

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FooBs[12].Sum}" />
```

You can imagine that I dont want to have a Index there, since I need to update it through ComboBoxes in the UI.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm struggling to understand how your current binding expression is actually presenting the **sum**, as your **converter** seems to just return the **FooB** object itself, and not it's **sum** property - so unless you've got a specific **ToString()** implementation on your **FooB** class that formats it to present the **sum**, I'm completely lost.

Secondly, I think your problem stems from the fact that your **MultiBinding** is based off of two properties only - **Data.SelectedId1** and **Data.SelectedId2**, therefore, unless either of those two properties change, the **MultiBinding** is not going to receive a **PropertyChanged** event and update.

A change of value of the **sum** property of your result is neither of the two, and so this is most likely why the view is not being updated.

I'm racking my brain as the best way to solve this, perhaps you should just handle this in the ViewModel, having a property named **CurrentFooB** or something that you can bind to. You would then set this value to the corresponding **FooB** instance in the **SelectionChanged** event handlers of your combo box.

Your binding would then look something like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Foos}>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CurrentFooB.Sum}"/>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Now, provided that **FooB** implements INotifyPropertyChanged, your view should update when the **sum** of the currently found **FooB** changes.

EDIT 1 (attempt at setting the source of the binding dynamically):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Foos}>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>

                <Binding Path="Sum">

                    <Binding.Source>

                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetCorrectFooB}">
                            <Binding Binding="."></Binding>
                            <Binding Binding="Data.SelectedId1"></Binding>
                            <Binding Binding="Data.SelectedId2"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>

                    </Binding.Source>

                </Binding>

            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>

        </DataGridTextColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didnt provide the information about how I get the `Sum` property in my example, sorry for this. In my real life application, I tried it both ways, with `.ToString()` and just passing the `.Sum` property in the converter, both with no luck like you already explained. You are saying that I would need to provide a `CurrentFooB` property to `Foo` and update all instance in the grid with the correct `FooB`?

Comment: I kinda hoped that there would be a way, to get a object maybe through source property in binding or I dont know... and just specify the Path to Sum. OR have a multibinding inside a binding, so that the source/datacontext could be bound per mutlibinding to get the correct FooB and the Binding itselft just specifies the Path... some in build WPF/XAML stuff without codebehind.

Comment: Yeah I can see your concern, and I'm sure there must be a way. Off the top of my head... uhhh.. what if you could use your current MultiBinding to set the DataContext of another binding that just binds to the Sum property?

Comment: This way it would work, wouldnt it? Since the DataContext would be and instance of FooB, and the Binding would provide the Path of the DataContext, this way when the Sum gets notified for a propertychanged. The underlying DataBinding would check "Hey my DataContext is FooB, and my Path to it is Sum so update", but thats just wild imagination since there is no nested Bind --> MultiBinding. Something like `<Binding> <Binding.DataContext> <MultiBinding> <Binding /> <Binding /> </MultiBinding> </Binding.DataContext> </Binding>`. or the same with `<Binding.Source>`

Comment: I hope so! :P Check my edited answer, I just realised using the Source property of the Binding rather than DataContext may be better.

Comment: LOL. Thats really possible to do? Never heard about it... Gona give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: As I believed specifing the Source Property over a Multibinding isnt possible, because you can only do it with DependencyProperties from a DependecyObject and Binding.Source isnt one.

Comment: Good point. This is a tough one to do purely in the view. My latest thought is whether or not some kind of DataTemplate could be applied to handle this Binding...